# 3 Level Dependent Dropdown Menu with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Hey everyone so I'm pretty new when it comes to Jquery & javascript & i'm working with some code left over from a previous developer. I need the values that show in each dropdown menu to be dependent on the one above it, and only the correct values to show for each option. I've looked around and have found information on 2-stage dropdowns in this way, but never on adding an extra stage after that. Here's the code I have below:

```js
$(function(){
  var $cat = $("#category1"),
      $subcat = $("#category2"),
      $volt = $("#category3");

      $cat.on("change",function(){
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
        $subcat.val("");
        if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
        $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
        $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
      });

      $subcat.on("change",function(){
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        $volt.find("option").attr("style","");
        $volt.val("");
        if(!_rel) return $volt.prop("disabled",true);
        $volt.find("[rel="+_rel+_rel+"]").show();
        $volt.prop("disabled",false);
      });

});
```

```css
#category2 option{
        display:none;
    }
    
    #category2 option.label{
        display:block;
    }
    
    #category3 option{
        display:none;
    }
    
    #category3 option.label{
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
        <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">First Dropdown Menu:</td>
                <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
                    <select name="category1" id="category1">
                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        <option value="Option1">ONE</option>
                        <option value="Option2">TWO</option>
                        <option value="Option3">THREE</option>
                        <option value="Option4">FOUR</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <form id="formname1" name="formname1" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
            <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="middle">Second Dropdown Menu:</td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                    <select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
                        <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
    <!-- R -->
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R80">80</option>
    <!-- H -->
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H80">80</option>
    <!-- L -->
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L80">80</option>
    <!-- B -->
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B80">80</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <form id="formname2" name="formname2" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
            <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="middle">Third Dropdown Menu</td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                    <select disabled="disabled" id="category3" name="category3">
    <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
    <!-- R -->
                        <option rel="R12" value="12v1">R12V1</option>
                        <option rel="R24" value="R24v1">R24V1</option>
                        <option rel="R36" value="R36v1">R36V1</option>
                        <option rel="R48" value="R48v1">R48V1</option>
                        <option rel="R80" value="R80v1">R80V1</option>
    <!-- H -->
                        <option rel="H12" value="H12v1">H12V1</option>
                        <option rel="H24" value="H24v1">H24V1</option>
                        <option rel="H36" value="H36v1">H36V1</option>
                        <option rel="H48" value="H48v1">H48V1</option>
                        <option rel="H80" value="H80v1">H80V1</option>
    <!-- L -->
                        <option rel="L12" value="L12v1">L12V1</option>
                        <option rel="L24" value="L24v1">L24V1</option>
                        <option rel="L36" value="L36v1">L36V1</option>
                        <option rel="L48" value="L48v1">L48V1</option>
                        <option rel="L80" value="L80v1">L80V1</option>
    <!-- B -->
                        <option rel="B12" value="B12v1">B12V1</option>
                        <option rel="B24" value="B24v1">B24V1</option>
                        <option rel="B36" value="B36v1">B36V1</option>
                        <option rel="B48" value="B48v1">B48V1</option>
                        <option rel="B80" value="B80v1">B80V1</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </html>
```

I can get the 2nd menu to work correctly, but the third menu always just shows everything, or doesn't work at all. I can't get it to depend on the values of the 2nd menu. Does anyone know how to solve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to change

```
$volt.find("[rel="+_rel+_rel+"]").show();
```

into

```
$volt.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
```

```js
$(function(){
    
      var $cat = $("#category1"),
          $subcat = $("#category2"),
          $volt = $("#category3");

          $cat.on("change",function(){
            var _rel = $(this).val();
            $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
            $subcat.val("");
            if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
            $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
            $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
          });

          $subcat.on("change",function(){
          debugger;
            var _rel = $(this).val();
            $volt.find("option").attr("style","");
            $volt.val("");
            if(!_rel) return $volt.prop("disabled",true);
            $volt.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
            $volt.prop("disabled",false);
          });
    
    });
```

```css
#category2 option{
        display:none;
    }
    
    #category2 option.label{
        display:block;
    }
    
    #category3 option{
        display:none;
    }
    
    #category3 option.label{
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
      <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
          <tr>
              <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">First Dropdown Menu:</td>
              <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
                  <select name="category1" id="category1">
                      <option value="">Please Select</option>
                      <option value="Option1">ONE</option>
                      <option value="Option2">TWO</option>
                      <option value="Option3">THREE</option>
                      <option value="Option4">FOUR</option>
                  </select>
              </td>
          </tr>
  <form id="formname1" name="formname1" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
          <tr>
              <td align="right" valign="middle">Second Dropdown Menu:</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle">
                  <select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
                      <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
  <!-- R -->
                      <option rel="Option1" value="R12">12</option>
                      <option rel="Option1" value="R24">24</option>
                      <option rel="Option1" value="R36">36</option>
                      <option rel="Option1" value="R48">48</option>
                      <option rel="Option1" value="R80">80</option>
  <!-- H -->
                      <option rel="Option2" value="H12">12</option>
                      <option rel="Option2" value="H24">24</option>
                      <option rel="Option2" value="H36">36</option>
                      <option rel="Option2" value="H48">48</option>
                      <option rel="Option2" value="H80">80</option>
  <!-- L -->
                      <option rel="Option3" value="L12">12</option>
                      <option rel="Option3" value="L24">24</option>
                      <option rel="Option3" value="L36">36</option>
                      <option rel="Option3" value="L48">48</option>
                      <option rel="Option3" value="L80">80</option>
  <!-- B -->
                      <option rel="Option4" value="B12">12</option>
                      <option rel="Option4" value="B24">24</option>
                      <option rel="Option4" value="B36">36</option>
                      <option rel="Option4" value="B48">48</option>
                      <option rel="Option4" value="B80">80</option>
                  </select>
              </td>
          </tr>
  <form id="formname2" name="formname2" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
          <tr>
              <td align="right" valign="middle">Third Dropdown Menu</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle">
                  <select disabled="disabled" id="category3" name="category3">
  <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
  <!-- R -->
                      <option rel="R12" value="12v1">R12V1</option>
                      <option rel="R24" value="R24v1">R24V1</option>
                      <option rel="R36" value="R36v1">R36V1</option>
                      <option rel="R48" value="R48v1">R48V1</option>
                      <option rel="R80" value="R80v1">R80V1</option>
  <!-- H -->
                      <option rel="H12" value="H12v1">H12V1</option>
                      <option rel="H24" value="H24v1">H24V1</option>
                      <option rel="H36" value="H36v1">H36V1</option>
                      <option rel="H48" value="H48v1">H48V1</option>
                      <option rel="H80" value="H80v1">H80V1</option>
  <!-- L -->
                      <option rel="L12" value="L12v1">L12V1</option>
                      <option rel="L24" value="L24v1">L24V1</option>
                      <option rel="L36" value="L36v1">L36V1</option>
                      <option rel="L48" value="L48v1">L48V1</option>
                      <option rel="L80" value="L80v1">L80V1</option>
  <!-- B -->
                      <option rel="B12" value="B12v1">B12V1</option>
                      <option rel="B24" value="B24v1">B24V1</option>
                      <option rel="B36" value="B36v1">B36V1</option>
                      <option rel="B48" value="B48v1">B48V1</option>
                      <option rel="B80" value="B80v1">B80V1</option>
                  </select>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Your advice seems sound but even after implementing that change, I still get the same result with the third dropdown not being dependent on the second (although for some frustrating reason it works here when I click on 'run code snippet'). Is there anything else I might be doing wrong to stop it from working?

Comment: You will need to provide more info regarding "not being dependent on second". What you select and what you get vs. what you expect to get there?

Comment: Ok sure what I am getting currently is that any option selected in the 2nd dropdown menu shows all of the options that exist in the 3rd dropdown. What I want is to select something in the 2nd dropdown (ex: <option rel="Option1" value="R12">12</option>) and then get relevant results that only relate to that option in the third, not everything that exists (i would only want to see ex: <option rel="R12" value="12v1">R12V1</option>). Still for some reason I'm getting everything...

Comment: I'm getting exactly this. Selected "one" in first select, "12" in second, and the third give me only R12V1. Which browser you checking?

Comment: i've been using chrome. I get the correct result when I "run code snippet" here but actually on my website it doesn't work... So I'm wondering if maybe it's something (maybe really basic since I'm new to jquery) that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you change the code in your website to the one provided here in the snippet? Did you see the differences between your original code and mine?

Comment: I had changed it to your code, copied and pasted exactly, and it wasn't working, but in the end I got it to work by clearing all my browsing history & data on the browser, and reloading, and suddenly it worked. Tried it on a few different web browsers as well, seems to work well except on Safari, but I'm guessing that would be a different question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are specifying `_rel` twice in 
 `$volt.find("[rel="+_rel+_rel+"]").show();`. Simply remove one of these.

I'd also recommend changing the second variable name to `_rel2`, as in the following example:

```css
#category2 option{
        display:none;
    }
    
    #category2 option.label{
        display:block;
    }
    
    #category3 option{
        display:none;
    }
    
    #category3 option.label{
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
    
      var $cat = $("#category1"),
          $subcat = $("#category2"),
          $volt = $("#category3");

          $cat.on("change",function(){
            var _rel = $(this).val();
            $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
            $subcat.val("");
            if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
            $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
            $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
          });

          $subcat.on("change",function(){
            var _rel2 = $(this).val();
            $volt.find("option").attr("style","");
            $volt.val("");
            if(!_rel2) return $volt.prop("disabled",true);
            $volt.find("[rel="+_rel2+"]").show();
            $volt.prop("disabled",false);
          });
    
    });
    </script>
    <form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
        <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">First Dropdown Menu:</td>
                <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
                    <select name="category1" id="category1">
                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        <option value="Option1">ONE</option>
                        <option value="Option2">TWO</option>
                        <option value="Option3">THREE</option>
                        <option value="Option4">FOUR</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <form id="formname1" name="formname1" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
            <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="middle">Second Dropdown Menu:</td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                    <select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
                        <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
    <!-- R -->
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R80">80</option>
    <!-- H -->
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H80">80</option>
    <!-- L -->
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L80">80</option>
    <!-- B -->
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B80">80</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <form id="formname2" name="formname2" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
            <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="middle">Third Dropdown Menu</td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                    <select disabled="disabled" id="category3" name="category3">
    <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
    <!-- R -->
                        <option rel="R12" value="12v1">R12V1</option>
                        <option rel="R24" value="R24v1">R24V1</option>
                        <option rel="R36" value="R36v1">R36V1</option>
                        <option rel="R48" value="R48v1">R48V1</option>
                        <option rel="R80" value="R80v1">R80V1</option>
    <!-- H -->
                        <option rel="H12" value="H12v1">H12V1</option>
                        <option rel="H24" value="H24v1">H24V1</option>
                        <option rel="H36" value="H36v1">H36V1</option>
                        <option rel="H48" value="H48v1">H48V1</option>
                        <option rel="H80" value="H80v1">H80V1</option>
    <!-- L -->
                        <option rel="L12" value="L12v1">L12V1</option>
                        <option rel="L24" value="L24v1">L24V1</option>
                        <option rel="L36" value="L36v1">L36V1</option>
                        <option rel="L48" value="L48v1">L48V1</option>
                        <option rel="L80" value="L80v1">L80V1</option>
    <!-- B -->
                        <option rel="B12" value="B12v1">B12V1</option>
                        <option rel="B24" value="B24v1">B24V1</option>
                        <option rel="B36" value="B36v1">B36V1</option>
                        <option rel="B48" value="B48v1">B48V1</option>
                        <option rel="B80" value="B80v1">B80V1</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </html>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're code is almost perfect.  You just need to adjust this line:

```
$volt.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
```

to get the right value to `show()`

```js
$(function(){
    
      var $cat = $("#category1"),
          $subcat = $("#category2"),
          $volt = $("#category3");

          $cat.on("change",function(){
            var _rel = $(this).val();
            $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
            $subcat.val("");
            if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
            $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
            $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
          });

          $subcat.on("change",function(){
          debugger;
            var _rel = $(this).val();
            $volt.find("option").attr("style","");
            $volt.val("");
            if(!_rel) return $volt.prop("disabled",true);
            $volt.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
            $volt.prop("disabled",false);
          });
    
    });
```

```css
#category2 option{
        display:none;
    }
    
    #category2 option.label{
        display:block;
    }
    
    #category3 option{
        display:none;
    }
    
    #category3 option.label{
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
        <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">First Dropdown Menu:</td>
                <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
                    <select name="category1" id="category1">
                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        <option value="Option1">ONE</option>
                        <option value="Option2">TWO</option>
                        <option value="Option3">THREE</option>
                        <option value="Option4">FOUR</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <form id="formname1" name="formname1" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
            <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="middle">Second Dropdown Menu:</td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                    <select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
                        <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
    <!-- R -->
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option1" value="R80">80</option>
    <!-- H -->
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option2" value="H80">80</option>
    <!-- L -->
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option3" value="L80">80</option>
    <!-- B -->
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B12">12</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B24">24</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B36">36</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B48">48</option>
                        <option rel="Option4" value="B80">80</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <form id="formname2" name="formname2" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >
            <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="middle">Third Dropdown Menu</td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                    <select disabled="disabled" id="category3" name="category3">
    <option class="label" value>Please Select</option>
    <!-- R -->
                        <option rel="R12" value="12v1">R12V1</option>
                        <option rel="R24" value="R24v1">R24V1</option>
                        <option rel="R36" value="R36v1">R36V1</option>
                        <option rel="R48" value="R48v1">R48V1</option>
                        <option rel="R80" value="R80v1">R80V1</option>
    <!-- H -->
                        <option rel="H12" value="H12v1">H12V1</option>
                        <option rel="H24" value="H24v1">H24V1</option>
                        <option rel="H36" value="H36v1">H36V1</option>
                        <option rel="H48" value="H48v1">H48V1</option>
                        <option rel="H80" value="H80v1">H80V1</option>
    <!-- L -->
                        <option rel="L12" value="L12v1">L12V1</option>
                        <option rel="L24" value="L24v1">L24V1</option>
                        <option rel="L36" value="L36v1">L36V1</option>
                        <option rel="L48" value="L48v1">L48V1</option>
                        <option rel="L80" value="L80v1">L80V1</option>
    <!-- B -->
                        <option rel="B12" value="B12v1">B12V1</option>
                        <option rel="B24" value="B24v1">B24V1</option>
                        <option rel="B36" value="B36v1">B36V1</option>
                        <option rel="B48" value="B48v1">B48V1</option>
                        <option rel="B80" value="B80v1">B80V1</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```